# Unlock screen from command line

Tags: unity, virtualbox, keyboard, lock-screen

I was using virtualbox on a laptop and closed the lid which locked the screen and sleep the computer. Now it came back from sleep, the screen is locked, but I can not type my password. The mouse work, I can set focus in the password box, but typing does nothing.

I guess the keyboard is held by virtualbox.

I tried plugin in a keyboard, no luck. I tried killing unity-panel-service --lockscreen-mode, it seems to have a watchdog that restart it.

I'll find some command line to sleep my vm, but is there anyway to unlock the screen from command line ?

Comment: "vboxmanage controlvm <VMName> savestate" --
saves the state of the vm then in my case I have no other work in progress so I just restarted lightdm.

Comment: have you tried to SIGSTOP vbox?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to TTY and run the command:

```
sleep 5; xdotool type <yourpassword>; xdotool key Return
```

and then go back to the login screen and click in the password box. Wait ~5 secs and your password will be typed and enter will have been pressed.

My pronouns are He / Him

Comment: Sounds good, but it refuse my password ???

Comment: One should use "read pwd < /dev/stdin", type your password then use $pwd in place of <yourpassword> so that your password is not saved in history or use HISTIGNORE.

Comment: xdotool type abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ouput qbcdefghijkl~nopqrstuvwxywcq ? But works fine on some other computer. That one was installed in french, the installer set a few things fr_FR instead of fr_CA. This seems to be the problem.

Comment: Why does this work when entered on a shell but not when run from a script in `/lib/systemd/system-sleep`?

Comment: @JellicleCat I guess because no x screen is attached to systmd?

Comment: @Tim : thanks. With your guidance, I incorporated this answer to successfully use xdotool on the login screen from `system-sleep`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10721288/507721

Comment: Additionally, in my script, I needed to run `xdotool` as my own user, not as root (which matters because `system-sleep`'s scripts run as root.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to unlock one X session from another of them as reached by pressing ctrl+alt+f key, but you could try killing all x sessions if you need to log back in by using `sudo killall Xorg` , but that logs you out of all x sessions. Sorry I don't have much more help to offer, but as I know of they all run independently and without editing the ramdisk are completely separate, with the login screen running on top making editing it almost impossible.

Comment: You can normally set your DISPLAY variable to access you X session from a virtual terminal, but to be helpful, there should be a command to tell unity to unlock the screen.

Comment: but without accessing a terminal from that specific x session i don't think it's possible

Comment: Type ctrl-alt-F1, log in, type "export DISPLAY=:0". This terminal is now the same as a terminal inside you X session, you can start X programs and they will appear in the virtual terminal at ctrl-alt-F7. To ensure you are allowed to access the session, the file $HOME/.Xauthority contains the credentials needed to access a particular X instance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `ps x` from an ssh shell to find the PID (e.g. 1234) of a command running under X
2. Type `cat /proc/1234/environ | xargs -0 -L1 echo | grep Y=` to show the DISPLAY and XAUTHORITY environment variables
3. Copy those lines with `export`: `export DISPLAY=:0` `export XAUTHORITY=xxx`
4. Now you can run `xdotool` or whatever.

I found that I had to use `xdotool key Return` before the login prompt would recognise keypresses from x11vnc to let me type the real one normally.