# Unlock Unity lockscreen from command line

Tags: command-line, unity, lock-screen

How do I unlock the lock screen in Unity from command line?

`gnome-screensaver-command -l` locks the screen, but `gnome-screensaver-command -d` doesn't unlock the lockscreen.

Is there another way to unlock the lock screen from the command line?
Not via ssh, via script, for example:

```
gnome-screensaver-command -l && sleep 5 && <command to unlock>
```

Comment: `gnome-screensaver-command -d` doesn't unlock it because [it's not meant to](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/gnome-screensaver-command.1.html).  It only deactivates the screensaver, but it won't log in as any user, that's why it doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unlock screen from command line](http://askubuntu.com/questions/505177/unlock-screen-from-command-line)

Comment: @M.Becerra is there an easy way to do it, if no with this command?
i saw that post, but i could find a satisfying answer

Comment: Depends on what you want to do exactly. Do you want to **lock** (so that you would have to log in again) or just show the screensaver?

Comment: If you read the `man gnome-screensaver-command` , it says for  `-d`  "unblank the screen". So it is not meant to be unlocking if your session is locked. Only turning on the display if it has been blanked out/turned off.

Comment: i want to lock so that i have to log in again and a script which is able to unlock (after a certain amount of time, or when executed via ssh for example)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Ubuntu 16.04 and later:

```
loginctl unlock-sessions
```

No need for root, but needs session permission obviously.

Note:
By default `gnome-screensaver-command -d` doesn't work anymore in Unity but with this [workaround](https://askubuntu.com/a/576897/119231) (enable on-screen keyboard) it does. Works for both 14.04 and 16.04.

Comment: This also works in Ubuntu 14.04.5.